# Extract userdata from table,using lua c API

Tags: c++, c, lua, lua-table, lua-api

I use lua c api to loop the variables in a table, like this

lua script:

```
array = {0,1,2,3}
```

lua c api

```
lua_getglobal(l, "array");
if(lua_isnil(l, -1)) {

}
lua_pushnil(l);
while(lua_next(l, -2)) {

    int value=(int)lua_tonumber(l, -1);
    printf("%d \n",value);

    lua_pop(l, 1);
}
```

and I can get the result

0 
1 
2 
3

Then I want to put some userdata objs into the table
and then loop them in the c api

lua script

```
foo0 = Foo.new("fred0")
foo1 = Foo.new("fred0")
foo2 = Foo.new("fred0")
foo3 = Foo.new("fred0")
array = {foo0,foo1,foo2,foo3}
```

lua c api

```
extern "C"
{
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"
}

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const std::string & name) : name(name)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo is born" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string Add(int a, int b)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << name << ": " << a << " + " << b << " = " << (a+b);
        return ss.str();
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo is gone" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string name;
};


int l_Foo_constructor(lua_State * l)
{
    const char * name = luaL_checkstring(l, 1);

    Foo ** udata = (Foo **)lua_newuserdata(l, sizeof(Foo *));
    *udata = new Foo(name);

    luaL_getmetatable(l, "luaL_Foo");

    lua_setmetatable(l, -2);

    return 1;
}




Foo * l_CheckFoo(lua_State * l, int n)
{
    return *(Foo **)luaL_checkudata(l, n, "luaL_Foo");
}

int l_Foo_add(lua_State * l)
{

    return 1;
}

int l_Foo_destructor(lua_State * l)
{
    Foo * foo = l_CheckFoo(l, 1);
    delete foo;

    return 0;
}

void RegisterFoo(lua_State * l)
{
    luaL_Reg sFooRegs[] =
    {
        { "new", l_Foo_constructor },
        { "add", l_Foo_add },
        { "__gc", l_Foo_destructor },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };

    luaL_newmetatable(l, "luaL_Foo");

    luaL_register(l, NULL, sFooRegs);

    lua_pushvalue(l, -1);

    lua_setfield(l, -1, "__index");

    lua_setglobal(l, "Foo");
}

int main()
{
    lua_State * l = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(l);
    RegisterFoo(l);

    int erred = luaL_dofile(l,"/Volumes/Work/CODE/Test/testStatic/testStatic/kami.txt");
    if(erred)
        std::cout << "Lua error: " << luaL_checkstring(l, -1) << std::endl;



    lua_getglobal(l, "array");
    if(lua_isnil(l, -1)) {
        //return std::vector();
    }
    lua_pushnil(l);

    std::vector<Foo *> v;
    while(lua_next(l, -2)) {


        Foo * foo = l_CheckFoo(l, -1);//this line do not work
        //
        //
        //
        //
        //I don't know how to do it here.
        //
        //
        //
        //
        //v.push_back(foo);
        lua_pop(l, 1);
    }


//    for (Foo* theValue:v)
//    {
//        printf("==>%s",theValue->name.c_str());
//    }

    lua_close(l);

    return 0;
}
```

how to extract userdata from a table?
please help me,thank you.

Comment: `Foo *foo = l_CheckFoo(l, -1); // this line do not work`. What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: excuse for my poor english... I debug the code ,and It throws an exception at that line  ,it says "PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (bad argument #-1 (luaL_Foo expected, got table))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I soved it by myself

```
l_CheckFoo(l, -1);
```

should be

```
lua_touserdata(l, -1);
```

---

```
void * hehe=lua_touserdata(l, -1);

Foo ** haha=(Foo **)hehe;

Foo *f=*haha;

printf("%s \n",f->name.c_str());
```